# Google Coral M.2 Accelerator to RaspberryPi CM4

Tags: google-coral

my first question on stack overflow :).

So I am having troubles to figure out the right Pinout on the M.2 connector for the PCIe connection.
Hopefully you can help me.

the datasheet says:

- PERn0 Pin 37
- PERp0 Pin 35
- PETn0 Pin 43
- PETp0 Pin 41

if this is from the Accelerator Module sight, I would connect e.g.

- PERn0 to PCIe_TX_N (on raspberry pi CM4)

Is this correct? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @timmey welcome here. I believe your question would better fit here: https://superuser.com/ as it is related to hardware. whereas SO is focused on software related issues.

Comment: We haven't been able to run Coral M.2 devices on PI CM4 yet. Please see https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu/issues/280 for details.